# How to bring the top bar in google maps in ios

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application in which i am opening goggle map in

webview with source and destination location but i am not able

to see the top bar which is displayed in the image attached.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yrwld.png

What i want is the top bar should also be displayed while opening map in iphone.
Kindly help.!In image it is showing the bar on the top.it is the default bar of google maps but i am not able get it .may i am not passing the correct url.the url i have given is :-

http://maps.google.com/?saddr=nagpur&daddr=pune&output=html

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about whether you are opening map in Safari or in same application using MapKit framework. But the top bar you are talking about will be displayed only if you open the map in Safari (as shown in code below), but if you are willing to have such control in your application map (ie using MapKit, MKMapView) you will have to code such control with same UI and functionality.

About the correct url for getting direction (in safari) see code:

```
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%@&daddr=%@",
                     [source stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                     [destination stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] 
                     ];
//where source and destination will be your address strings.    
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```